# Understand Redhat Yum mirrors issues

Tags: linux, redhat, yum

I'm using RHVH to manage my infrastructure VMs.

I've two bare metal servers in two different network subnets with same release version of RHVH.

I use an automated script to deploy VMs on both, and provision a docker repository file there on VMs.

The issue I'm facing is when I'm trying to query `container-selinux` package. It works on VMs from one of my bare metal servers, and not from the other.

first sever's VM:

```
[root@cpu-node0 ~]# /bin/repoquery --show-duplicates --plugins --disablerepo '' --enablerepo '' --qf  '%{name}|%{epoch}|%{version}|%{release}|%{arch}|%{repoid}' container-selinux
container-selinux|2|2.107|1.el7_6|noarch|extras
container-selinux|2|2.107|3.el7|noarch|extras
[root@cpu-node0 ~]#
```

Second server's VM :

```
[root@cpu-node0 ~]# /bin/repoquery --show-duplicates --plugins --disablerepo '' --enablerepo '' --qf  '%{name}|%{epoch}|%{version}|%{release}|%{arch}|%{repoid}' container-selinux
Could not match packages: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from docker-engine: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
[root@cpu-node0 ~]#
```

The yum repo configuration on both VMs running on each bare metal server:

```
[root@cpu-node0 ~]# ll /etc/yum.repos.d/
total 44
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1664  5 sept. 13:05 CentOS-Base.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1309  5 sept. 13:05 CentOS-CR.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  649  5 sept. 13:05 CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  314  5 sept. 13:05 CentOS-fasttrack.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  630  5 sept. 13:05 CentOS-Media.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1331  5 sept. 13:05 CentOS-Sources.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 6639  5 sept. 13:05 CentOS-Vault.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  369  2 mars  23:31 docker.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1050 17 sept. 23:25 epel.repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1149 17 sept. 23:25 epel-testing.repo
[root@cpu-node0 ~]#
```

docker.repo file content on both VMs :

```
[root@cpu-node0 ~]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/docker.repo 
[docker-ce]
name=Docker-CE Repository
baseurl=https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/$basearch/stable
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
keepcache=1
gpgkey=https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/gpg

[docker-engine]
name=Docker-Engine Repository
baseurl=https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
keepcache=1
gpgkey=https://yum.dockerproject.org/gpg
[root@cpu-node0 ~]#
```

Repo list on the first VM :

```
[root@cpu-node0 ~]# yum repolist
id du dépôt                                                                         nom du dépôt                                                                                                      statut
base/7/x86_64                                                                       CentOS-7 - Base                                                                                                   10 097
docker-ce/x86_64                                                                    Docker-CE Repository                                                                                                  68
!docker-engine                                                                      Docker-Engine Repository                                                                                             110
epel/x86_64                                                                         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                    13 199
extras/7/x86_64                                                                     CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                                                    323
updates/7/x86_64                                                                    CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                                                 1 478
repolist: 25 275
[root@cpu-node0 ~]#
```

Yum repo list on the second VM:

```
[root@cpu-node0 ~]# yum repolist
https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Essai d'un autre miroir.
To address this issue please refer to the below wiki article 

https://wiki.centos.org/yum-errors

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please use https://bugs.centos.org/.

docker-ce/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                                                          |  40 kB  00:00:05     
https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Essai d'un autre miroir.
id du dépôt                                                                         nom du dépôt                                                                                                      statut
base/7/x86_64                                                                       CentOS-7 - Base                                                                                                   10 097
docker-ce/x86_64                                                                    Docker-CE Repository                                                                                                  68
docker-engine                                                                       Docker-Engine Repository                                                                                               0
epel/x86_64                                                                         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                    13 199
extras/7/x86_64                                                                     CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                                                    323
updates/7/x86_64                                                                    CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                                                 1 478
repolist: 25 165
[root@cpu-node0 ~]#
```

I also get the message below when trying to curl the repository URL :

```
[root@cpu-node0 ~]#curl https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7/repodata/repomd.xml

<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head></head>

<body>

  <h1>Notice: Shutting down dockerproject.org APT and YUM repos 2020-03-31</h1>

  <p>Docker will be shutting down the deprecated APT and YUM repositories hosted at "dockerproject.org" and "dockerproject.com" on the 31st of March 2020.</p>

  <p>We noticed that this project is referencing one of these repositories, and recommend updating to use the "download.docker.com" repository to prevent disruption.</p>

  <p>More info: https://www.docker.com/blog/changes-dockerproject-org-apt-yum-repositories/ </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Looks like docker does not want anyone to use this repo anymore. Probably they started issuing the error from today I guess.

Of course the two VMs do not have `subscription-manager` package installed, neither subscription attached, they don't need actually in our context, but why is there a mirror issue on one VM and not on the other, whose OS and system configuration is the same on both, except that they are locate in two different networks?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: understood @Barmar, but I saw the same related questions here in stack overflow. However I posted my question on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like yum docker-engine querying came back to a normal state

Even docker project url curling is working without the warning message seen in my first post

Looks like the deployment process hit a bad state in the public repo and hence caused these errors.